# Moving Two Rectangles with keyboard in Javafx

Tags: javafx, keyboard-events

I'm fairly new to programming, and I've been working on a two player Pong game with JavaFX. One player uses W/S to move his "paddle" and the other player uses the Up/Down arrows for his. The problem I keep having is that only one player can move his paddle at a time. I can't figure out how to get it so they can each move their individual paddles at the same time. I had one keyboard event handler control both paddles, I thought that was the problem. I made two separate keyboard handlers, but got another set of problems tat I think is caused by the built in setFocusTraversable methods. I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense. Any ideas?

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class Game{

Rectangle leftPaddle;
double leftPaddleY = 260;

Rectangle rightPaddle;
double rightPaddleY = 260;

public void createGame(Group gameDisplay){

    //creates background
    Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0,0,800,600);
    background.getStyleClass().add("background");

    //draws field lines
    Canvas game = new Canvas(800, 600);
    GraphicsContext gc = game.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("WHITE"));
    gc.setLineWidth(5);
    gc.strokeLine(400, 0, 400, 600);
    gc.strokeOval(300, 200, 200, 200);
    gc.strokeRect(0, 150, 100, 300);
    gc.strokeRect(700, 150, 100, 300);
    gc.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("BLACK"));
    gc.setLineWidth(8);
    gc.strokeRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    //creates red paddle
    leftPaddle = new Rectangle(30, leftPaddleY, 20, 70);
    leftPaddle.setOnKeyPressed(paddleMovement);
    leftPaddle.setFocusTraversable(true);
    leftPaddle.setFill(Color.RED);

    //creates blue paddle
    rightPaddle = new Rectangle(750, rightPaddleY, 20, 70);
    rightPaddle.setOnKeyPressed(paddleMovement);
    rightPaddle.setFocusTraversable(true);
    rightPaddle.setFill(Color.BLUE);


    gameDisplay.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("GameDisplay.css").toExternalForm());
    gameDisplay.getChildren().addAll(background, game, leftPaddle, rightPaddle);
}

public EventHandler<KeyEvent> paddleMovement = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

        //red paddle movement
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.W)){
            leftPaddle.setY(leftPaddleY -= 6);
            if(leftPaddle.getY() < 0){
                leftPaddle.setY(0);
                leftPaddleY = 0;
            }
        }
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.S)){
            leftPaddle.setY(leftPaddleY += 6);
            if(leftPaddle.getY() < 0){
                leftPaddle.setY(0);
                leftPaddleY = 0;
            }
        }

        //blue paddle movement
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP)){
            rightPaddle.setY(rightPaddleY -= 6);
            if(rightPaddle.getY() < 0){
                rightPaddle.setY(0);
                rightPaddleY = 0;
            }
        }
        if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DOWN)){
            rightPaddle.setY(rightPaddleY += 6);
            if(rightPaddle.getY() < 0){
                rightPaddle.setY(0);
                rightPaddleY = 0;
            }
        }

    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyPressed` event will only be triggered repeatedly for the last key pressed.

To work around this, just "remember" the desired movement for each paddle and listen to the `keyReleased` event too. You can execute the movements using a `AnimationTimer` to execute the updates every frame (you could also use a `Timeline` instead to have more control over the frequency of the updates).

Furthermore I recommend being a bit more restrictive with the visibility of your member variables, since usually you do not want other classes to be able to directly write to the fields of your class. Also I recommend handling the events in a single `Node`. Only one `Node` can have focus at a time and handling the event in different places just results in duplicate code.

```
public class Game {

    private Rectangle leftPaddle;
    private double leftPaddleY = 260;

    private Rectangle rightPaddle;
    private double rightPaddleY = 260;

    private double leftPaddleDY;
    private double rightPaddleDY;
    private AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            // update paddle positions
            leftPaddleY += leftPaddleDY;
            rightPaddleY += rightPaddleDY;
            if (leftPaddleY < 0) {
                leftPaddleY = 0;
            }
            if (rightPaddleY < 0) {
                rightPaddleY = 0;
            }

            leftPaddle.setY(leftPaddleY);
            rightPaddle.setY(rightPaddleY);
        }

    };

    public void createGame(Group gameDisplay) {

        //creates background
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
        background.getStyleClass().add("background");

        //draws field lines
        Canvas game = new Canvas(800, 600);
        GraphicsContext gc = game.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("WHITE"));
        gc.setLineWidth(5);
        gc.strokeLine(400, 0, 400, 600);
        gc.strokeOval(300, 200, 200, 200);
        gc.strokeRect(0, 150, 100, 300);
        gc.strokeRect(700, 150, 100, 300);
        gc.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("BLACK"));
        gc.setLineWidth(8);
        gc.strokeRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

        //creates red paddle
        leftPaddle = new Rectangle(30, leftPaddleY, 20, 70);
        leftPaddle.setFill(Color.RED);

        //creates blue paddle
        rightPaddle = new Rectangle(750, rightPaddleY, 20, 70);
        rightPaddle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        // register event handlers to Canvas
        game.setFocusTraversable(true);
        game.setOnKeyPressed(keyPressed);
        game.setOnKeyReleased(keyReleased);

        gameDisplay.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("GameDisplay.css").toExternalForm());
        gameDisplay.getChildren().addAll(background, game, leftPaddle, rightPaddle);
        // start updates of paddle positions
        timer.start();
    }

    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyReleased = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            // set movement to 0, if the released key was responsible for the paddle
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case W:
                case S:
                    leftPaddleDY = 0;
                    break;
                case UP:
                case DOWN:
                    rightPaddleDY = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyPressed = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            // start movement according to key pressed
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case W:
                    leftPaddleDY = -6;
                    break;
                case S:
                    leftPaddleDY = 6;
                    break;
                case UP:
                    rightPaddleDY = -6;
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    rightPaddleDY = 6;
                    break;
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. It works and it all makes sense now haha. I could not for the life of me figure out how to use the AnimationTimer. And thank you for the extra tips